# Passing another object into object vector

Tags: c++, oop, vector

I have have following classes: Product (abstract), Clothing (inherited from Product), Item (has aggregate object from product), and Cart (has a compositioned vector from Item (vector  items)).

My question is: when can I pass object from another class than Item into vector? For example: `items.push_back((Item(p, quantity)))`
Why this doesn't cause error, because this is not the same object type as vector.

```
void addEvent(Product *p, int quantity) {
    items.push_back((Item(p, quantity)));
}
```

Object created in main:

```
Clothing *obl4 = new Clothing(36, Gender::woman, "hose", 30);
```

And then added to the vector:

```
Cart nakup;

nakup.addEvent(obl4, 2);
```

Comment: How is `items` defined? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: its: vector <Item> items

Comment: So you are passing exactly the type it expects? Or how is `Item(p, quantity)` different from the `Item` you store in the vector?

Comment: I don't understand why can I create Clothing object in main and then store that object in Item vector. Those are not made from the same class.

Comment: But you are storing it in an `Item`, which is then stored in the vector?! You don't `push_back(p)`?!

Comment: @danilo You are not storing the `Clothing` object itself in the vector, you are storing an `Item` object that refers to the `Clothing` object.  BIG difference.

Answer (score 0):

> when can I pass object from another class than Item into vector? For example: `items.push_back(Item(p, quantity))` Why this doesn't cause error, because this is not the same object type as vector.

So, it appears that your `Cart` contains the data member

`std::vector<Item> items`

when you call `items.push_back(Item(p, quantity))` you are not passing a different class into `items`, you are constructing an `Item(p, quantity)`, and inserting it into `items`.

Comment: There is no polymorphism of `Item` in the question

Answer (score 0):

You have a `vector` of `Item` objects.  `addEvent()` is pushing an `Item` object into the `vector`, not the `Product*` itself.  So, there is no mismatch happening (provided that `Item` has a constructor that takes a `Product*` as input - you did not show what `Item` looks like).